# Restructuring meteor update snippet

Tags: meteor

I have this snippet of code

```
         Requestor.update({ _id: theid }, {$set: {
          "reqestmadebyid": doc.reqestmadebyid,
          "requestschoolid": doc.requestschoolid,
          "requestmadebynames": doc.requestmadebynames,
          "requestmadeon": doc.requestmadeon,
          "requesttype": doc.requesttype,
          "requestdescription": doc.requestdescription,
          "requestparameter1": doc.requestparameter1,
          "requestparameter2" : doc.requestparameter2,
          "requestparameter3" : doc.requestparameter3,
          "requestparameter4" : doc.requestparameter4,
          "requestparameter5" : doc.requestparameter5,
          "requestparameter6" : doc.requestparameter6,
          "requestparameter7" : doc.requestparameter7,
          "requeststatus" : doc.requeststatus,
          "requestdenialexplanation" : doc.requestdenialexplanation
             }
             });
```

which i am using to update a form. Is there a way i can make it smaller like we do during insert?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say this is smaller, but it's easier to maintain.

```
var fields = [
'reqestmadebyid', 
'requestschoolid', 
'requestmadebynames', 
'requestmadeon', 
'requesttype', 
'requestdescription', 
'requestparameter1', 
'requestparameter2', 
'requestparameter3', 
'requestparameter4', 
'requestparameter5', 
'requestparameter6', 
'requestparameter7', 
'requeststatus', 
'requestdenialexplanation'
];

var updateSet = fields.reduce(function(data, field) {
  return data[field] = doc[field];
}, {});

Requestor.update({ _id: theid }, {$set: updateSet});
```

More compact example using lodash npm package:

```
var fields = [
'reqestmadebyid', 
'requestschoolid', 
'requestmadebynames', 
'requestmadeon', 
'requesttype', 
'requestdescription', 
'requestparameter1', 
'requestparameter2', 
'requestparameter3', 
'requestparameter4', 
'requestparameter5', 
'requestparameter6', 
'requestparameter7', 
'requeststatus', 
'requestdenialexplanation'
];

Requestor.update({ _id: theid }, {$set: _.pick(doc, fields)});
```

Comment: That's some clever code.I am silently hoping meteor has a way of shortening this.

Comment: Something to make you smile,all hail this captain obvious https://github.com/udondan/meteor-bulk-collection-update

Comment: @LeQs If you want to update every poperty that `doc` object contains, you can simply write `Requestor.update({ _id: theid }, {$set: doc});`.

Comment: @LeQs Or, if you need **almost** every property, you can write this (using lodash): `var omitted = ['a', 'b']; Requestor.update({ _id: theid }, {$set: _.omit(doc, omitted)});`.